# assingning a variable to a style in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I used the following code for changing the content of a style..

```
$("#Button1").click(function () {

    var str="12";
    if ($('#additionalStyles').length) {
        $('#additionalStyles').remove();
    } else {
        $('head').append('<style id="additionalStyles">.noti_bubble:before{color: yellow; content:'"str"';}</style>');
    }
});
```

The actual css code is ......

```
.noti_bubble:before{
    position:absolute;
    padding:1px 2px 1px 2px;
    background-color:red;
    content:"5";
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    height : 11px;
    width: 15px;
}
```

The `jquery` changes the colour to yellow. but not change the content from 5 to 12....
pls help me....

Comment: You have not specified `content` in `$('head').append('<style id="a.......................`

Comment: Because you are setting it to empty string, not 12: `content:'';`

Comment: I see absolutely no reasons why value of unused `str` variable should have any impact on style... You probably want to update sample to show how you actually use that variable (or how "12" is used somewhere else).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is string concatenation issues in your script

```js
$("#Button1").click(function() {
  var str = "12";
  if ($('#additionalStyles').length) {
    $('#additionalStyles').remove();
  } else {
    $('head').append('<style id="additionalStyles">.noti_bubble:before{color: yellow; content:"' + str + '";}</style>');
  }
});
```

```css
.noti_bubble:before {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1px 2px 1px 2px;
  background-color: red;
  content: "5";
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 11px;
  width: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="Button1">Button1</button>
<span class="noti_bubble"></span>
```

---

But I would recommend using another class to change the style, if possible instead of adding a dynamic style definition(it is possible only if the content value is not dynamic)

```js
$("#Button1").click(function() {
  $('.noti_bubble').toggleClass('special');
});
```

```css
.noti_bubble:before {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1px 2px 1px 2px;
  background-color: red;
  content: "5";
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 11px;
  width: 15px;
}
.noti_bubble.special:before {
  color: yellow;
  content: "12";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="Button1">Button1</button>
<span class="noti_bubble"></span>
```

Comment: i changed my code as $('head').append('<style id="additionalStyles">.noti_bubble:before{color: yellow; content:"' + str + '";}</style>');   but the result is '+str'

Answer (score 0):

once try this :

```
 $('head').append('<style id="additionalStyles">.noti_bubble:before{color: yellow; content:"'+str+'";}</style>');
```

Comment: ys its workd...Is it a temporary change.?Then Instead of assigining simply var str="12" can we take this this value from a database and assign to it?

Comment: yes y not you can set it as an example through variable